# Modeling Encoder-Decoder according to instructions from a paper

Tags: python, keras, rnn

I am new to this field and I was reading a paper "Predicting citation counts based on deep neural network learning techniques". There the authors describe the code that they implemented if someone wants to reproduce the results. I tried to do this but I am not sure if I succeeded.

Here is their description:

```
-RNN module - SimpleRNN
-Output dimension of the encoder - 512
-The output layer - Dense layer
-Activation function - ReLU
-Overfitting prevention technique - Dropout with 0.2 rate
-Epochs - 100
Optimization algorithm - RMSProp
Learning rate - 10^{-5}
Batch size - 256
```

And here is my implementation. I am not sure if the model I created is sequence to sequence.

```
epocsh = 100
batch_size = 256
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.00001)
model =  keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(512, input_shape=[X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]],
                           activation='relu', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(9)
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

The summary of this model is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn (SimpleRNN)       (None, 154521, 512)       266240    
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 154521, 9)         4617      
=================================================================
Total params: 270,857
Trainable params: 270,857
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Update: Here is the dataset.

```
year  venue  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14
1989    234   0   1   2   3   4   5   5   5   5    8    8   10   11   12
1989    251   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0
1990    346   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I need to give as an input all the columns until c5, and try to predict the other c's (which are citation count for the upcoming years).

Answer (score 0):

What is the input and output? Assuming your input is a sequence of documents, you would need to convert it into some sort of embeddings (TF-IDF, any other). After that comes the RNN - which looks ok to me. The output of the RNN is equal to the number of timesteps (num of words in each doc?). For each timestep we predict using a Dense final layer. You have 9 outputs. Is it some sort of a classification across 9 different types of categories or levels of citation counts?

Overall looks ok with the above assumptions other than the fact that you are feeding raw data instead of using an embedding layer

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I added also the dataset that I am going to use. So what this model has to predict is the number of citations that each paper will receive in the consecutive years given the first 5 years, date of publication and the venue.

Comment: In that case you don't need embeddings. All your input data is in numbers. The output is also a set of numbers for the next 9 years. So I guess you are good to go. The basic model above should give you some initial output which you can try and fine-tune further..

Comment: The thing is that someone commented that this is not an encoder-decoder just a classifier. I am not sure how to make the transition to encoder-decoder.

Comment: Well - There is no decoder. We just have a Dense final layer. You don't need a decoder because you have nothing to translate. You just 'encode' using an RNN and using this encode data you make predictions via a dense layer. You can definitely improve the model by adding 'attention' during prediction. For the given problem that is the best you can do.

Comment: I am trying to remake what the paper said because I will compare my results to the authors results. Everywhere it says that RNN use LSTM or GRU but they didn't mention any such layers. I guess this is what they did. I have another problem if you are willing to help. I don't know who to feed the data. I get this error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 7]`

Comment: Thank you for the previous comment!

Comment: pl share the paper link.

Comment: This is the paper, I can also share the data if you want: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1751157718303821?via%3Dihub